# Run condition based on value of URL (Yii)

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I'm trying to do a simple bit of logic in a view, basically I want to say if the third parameter in the URL is 'update' run this logic otherwise run something else.

e.g

```
// if 3rd param is 'update' e.g URL http://acme.local/acme/competitions/update
{
  // RUN THIS BLOCK
} else {
  // RUN THIS INSTEAD
}
```

Can anyone recommend how to do this in Yii

Comment: update is action or query string parameter? in your e.g URL http://acme.local/acme/competitions/update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a suggestion, you can do this like below.

```
$check=Yii::app()->request->getQuery('update',NULL);
 if(!is_null($check)){

 //TRUE CONDITION,
 //YOU CAN USE $check VARIABLE WHICH HOLDS update $_GET VALUE 
 }else{
 //FALSE CONDITON
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yii::app()->controller->action->id
and Yii::app()->controller->id